# Fail to send message from popup.js in Chrome extension to background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I hope to send message from popup.js to background.js. When I click the button, the message will send to the background.js, and it will open a new tab for my specify website. I have check the popup.js and background.js and found that both of them are ok, only just can't send the message from popup.js to background.js.

popup.js

```
window.onload=function()
{
     document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function()
  {
     chrome.extension.sendMessage({command:"start"});
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request,sender,sendResponse)
    {
        switch(request.command)
        {
            case "command":
                openTab();
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
);

var openTab=function()
{
    chrome.windows.create
    (
        {
            url:"http://www.baidu.com",
            tabId:1
        }

    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a little error in your code: in the function you use to receive the message in the `background.js` script you are using the `switch` statement on the variable `request.command`, but then, inside it, you're checking for `case "command"`, when **you should check for `case "start"` instead, because you're sending a message which is `{command: "start"}`**.

The message is received, but checked against a string that doesn't match, and obviously your `openTab()` function will never be called.

To solve this issue you can either:

- Change the message you're sending from `popup.js`, like this:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: "command"});
  ```
- Or change the `case` statement in your `background.js` script:

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      switch(request.command) {
          case "start":
              openTab();
              break;
      }

      return true;
  });
  ```

Anyway, **I strongly recommend you to use the `chrome.runtime` API instead of `chrome.extension`**, which is outdated.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved the problem and now the new tab can be open successfully. But I also want to know that why I have to remove the **tabId** option in my **chrome.windows.create** to make it run?